# Want to know more about NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a active assignment working on NIFI.
Want to know below Question Answers?

1.IS NIFI has any encryption mechanism in buffered queue data? what all the security features.

2.We can do retention on buffered data?

3.How NIFI is having advantage working with HDFS?

4.How long nifi can hold buffer data.What if NIFI is stopped working ,will be any data lose?

5.How to deploy code in NIFI server.

Please help with Answers.

Comment: Isn't there a documentation for this product? Usually this is exactly what should been written down.

Comment: In nifi docs, i m not finding, goggling more for finding answers.@bryan bende can tell more for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Currently there is only an encrypted repository for provenance, but not for flow file repo and content repo. There is an EncryptContent processor that can be used to encrypt the content of the flow file. You can also create fine-grained security policies to restrict who can access each queue.
2. Yes, see the documentation on back-pressure and flow file expiration https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#settings
3. Not really sure what this question means... NiFi can be used to deliver data to HDFS, or retrieve data from it, but NiFi itself does not use HDFS.
4. The amount of data that can be buffered is based on how much disk and memory you have available. There isn't really a limitation imposed by NiFi. All data is persisted to disk and will not be lost unless you lose the disks.
5. Custom components are packaged as NARs and deployed to NiFi's lib directory and NiFi must be restarted. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Maven+Projects+for+Extensions

Comment: Thank you so much Bryan for your prompt response .I am really glad to have answers from you.I am writing back to you for clarify more doubts.    Start from question 3---> How NIFI is having advantage working with HDFS?  -->i am asking connect nifi to hdfs is more helpful in terms off other repository  like AWS.4.coming to new question- can we connect nifi to nifi working on different system and also i have to work on MINIFI .in google there is very less documentation.How to get more about this .My POC is connect minifi to nifi to get data from rosberrypi devices.

Comment: 3 - There is no right answer, AWS has S3 as an object store, HDFS is a general filesystem, whichever makes sense for you. 4 - Yes please read about site-to-site which is how two NiFi's communicate, and how MiNiFi communicates with NiFi. There are lots of articles out there... https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-an-iiot-system-using-apache-nifi-mqtt-and-raspberry-pi-ce1d6ed565bc

Comment: Thank you so much Bryan,it's really helpful

Comment: COuld you please any basic example of using remote processor gorup.i am planning to connect  two nifi using site to site in 2 different system

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#site-to-site

Comment: Hi Bryan, I have read concept of site to site and implementing same. How i am doing it ? i have two Ubuntu system. In both the system i have install HDF on top docker and accessing NIFI.Now in machine 1 ,i have used generateflow file processor and outputport. and in second cluster i have used remote access group and put file but when i am trying to connect RAG to  put file it is saying no output port . i checked by right click on RAG"Mange remote prt option "-it shoul d be there output port enable option but it is not showing .where i am doing mistake .

Comment: CONTD... where i am doing mistake . if i talk about RAG configuration - i give URL as (http://172.17.0.1:9090/nifi/,http://172.17.0.1:9090/nifi/) ,transport protocal -http,thats it .I used below link to implement. https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/88473/site-to-site-communication-between-secured-https-a.html